# Следующая запись по id но с сортировкой

Tags: php, mysql

Надо сделать переключение между записями - предыдущая и следующая. Применяю такой код:

```
$sql_next = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Все работает. Но как мне отсортировать записи по рейтингу? Пробовал так:

```
$sql_next = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < $id ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Не работает. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что конкретно вы хотите отсортировать по рейтингу ? Исходя из первого примера можно предположить, что вам нужна предыдущая по рейтингу строка. Но тогда вам в условии where надо проверять не на `id <` а на `rating <` и сравнивать разумеется с рейтингом. Но учитывая, что рейтинг возможно не уникальный надо предусмотреть случай и решить какую запись считать предыдущей если есть еще строки с таким же рейтингом как у той перед которой вы ищите

Comment: @Mike очевидно, что записи из таблицы.

Comment: Какие именно записи. Судя по указанному условию только те, у которых id меньше заданного. А какие надо на самом деле вам решать и пока это не указано в вопросе никто за вас не решит что же вы хотели получить

Comment: @Mike ох. Есть записи в таблице, пускай это будут посты/картинки/новости. Если я с главной страницы захожу на новость у которой id 5, и нажму кнопку "Следующая новость", то я перейду на новость с id 6. Это код моего первого примера. Далее. Если я перейду на новость (у нее рейтинг 55, например), из раздела "Популярные новости", и нажав на кнопку "Следующая новость", то я должен буду перейти на новость, у которой рейтинг 54. Так понятно?

Comment: да, так понятно и это полностью соответствует моему предположению, которое я высказал в первом коменте. И там я даже написал что решение может быть только одно `SELECT * FROM table WHERE rating < $rating ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 1` конечно надо сделать так что бы в $rating оказалось значение рейтинга текущей записи. И это работает в случае если в таблице не бывает строк с одинаковыми рейтингами, а если бывают то вам надо решать в каком порядке листать строки у которых рейтинг одинаков

Comment: @Mike о, спасибо, заработало. А далее они они сортируются сами и ни как не конфликтуют.

Comment: можно сортировать и по паре `rating, id`